# Python: can't retrieve ipv6 with socket.getaddrinfo() on AWS

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-web-services, networking

On my laptop, I can run

```
import socket
print(socket.getaddrinfo('yahoo.com', 80))
```

Perfectly fine and it would return the ipv4 addresses and ipv6. However, once I do it on my Amazon Web services server, it doesn't seem to return the ipv6 address, it does for a few sites though. Is this a DNS issue? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless something has changed recently, AWS doesn't support IPv6 except on the US East Ohio data center.  (And it's not easy to get that configured correctly either!)

But if you really want IPv6 DNS, you can use socket.getaddrinfo instead.

```
print(socket.getaddrinfo("yahoo.com", 80, socket.AF_INET6))
```

No guarantee if the subsequent socket connection with that IPv6 address works -
 as you may not be on an IPv6 network.  You can combo it with `socket.has_ipv6` property.  But even that will return True on most Windows machines that have an auto configured Terredo address.